# Can a node app connect / write to MongoDB while being run as PM2 service?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, pm2

I have this Node app here, which makes a request to an api to get some stock data, loops through that stock data and then writes it to a Mongo DB every 5 minutes. I am running it on a Digital Ocean server with PM2 as a service. However, after letting it run a for a day I don't see any data in the DB. I don't see any signs that the service wasn't running or had any errors so I'm wondering if maybe it is because a PM 2 service can't write to the DB? Maybe a ports issue? Any guidance would be awesome!

```
// -- Dependancies --
// Request and MongoDB
const request = require('request');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


// Connect to database
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/stock-test')
    .then(() => {
        console.log('connected');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });


// Setup stockMoment Schema
const StockMomentSchema = new Schema({
    symbol: String,
    price: Number,
    size: Number,
    time: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});


// Create stockMoment model
StockMoment = mongoose.model('stockMoment', StockMomentSchema, 'stockPriceData');


// Setup Variables
const d = new Date();
let day = d.getDay()
let hour = d.getHours();



// Check time, run getMarketData function if market is open
function makeRequest() {
    if(day >= 1 && day <= 5) {
        if(hour >= 11 && hour <= 16) {
            getMarketData();
        }
    }
}


// Run request to get data, store data in MongoDB database
function getMarketData() {
    request({
        url: 'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/tops/last',
        json: true
    }, (err, res, body) => {
        if(err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }

        for(let i = 0; i < body.length; i++) {
            const stockMoment = new StockMoment({
                symbol: body[i].symbol,
                price: body[i].price,
                size: body[i].size,
                time: body[i].time,
            });
            stockMoment.save((err) => {
                if(err) return handleError(err);
                console.log('Saved!', i);
            });
            console.log(body[i]);
        }
    });
}


setInterval(makeRequest, 300000);
```

**PM2 Logs:**

```
PM2        | [2018-08-27T23:05:42.936Z] PM2 log: RPC socket file      : /home/evadmin/.pm2/rpc.sock
PM2        | [2018-08-27T23:05:42.937Z] PM2 log: BUS socket file      : /home/evadmin/.pm2/pub.sock
PM2        | [2018-08-27T23:05:42.937Z] PM2 log: Application log path : /home/evadmin/.pm2/logs
PM2        | [2018-08-27T23:05:42.937Z] PM2 log: Process dump file    : /home/evadmin/.pm2/dump.pm2
PM2        | [2018-08-27T23:05:42.937Z] PM2 log: Concurrent actions   : 2
PM2        | [2018-08-27T23:05:42.937Z] PM2 log: SIGTERM timeout      : 1600
PM2        | [2018-08-27T23:05:42.937Z] PM2 log: ===============================================================================
PM2        | [2018-08-27T23:05:42.972Z] PM2 log: Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:priceTimeSeries id:0
PM2        | [2018-08-27T23:05:42.977Z] PM2 log: App name:priceTimeSeries id:0 online
PM2        | [2018-08-27T23:08:02.026Z] PM2 log: Process 0 in a stopped status, starting it
PM2        | [2018-08-27T23:08:02.027Z] PM2 log: Stopping app:priceTimeSeries id:0
PM2        | [2018-08-27T23:08:02.042Z] PM2 log: App [priceTimeSeries] with id [0] and pid [1927], exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | [2018-08-27T23:08:02.139Z] PM2 log: pid=1927 msg=process killed
PM2        | [2018-08-27T23:08:02.140Z] PM2 log: Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:priceTimeSeries id:0
PM2        | [2018-08-27T23:08:02.145Z] PM2 log: App name:priceTimeSeries id:0 online

/home/evadmin/.pm2/logs/priceTimeSeries-error.log last 15 lines:
0|priceTim | (node:1927) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
0|priceTim | (node:2001) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.

/home/evadmin/.pm2/logs/priceTimeSeries-out.log last 15 lines:
0|priceTim | connected
0|priceTim | connected
```

Comment: I also have a digital api running as a service / PM2 and mongodb database. Everything is working very well. I'll take a look at your code. Problem should be another, in the PM2 logs what does it show? `pm2 logs` in bash.

Comment: Doesn't seem like there's anything wrong there either. I'll add it to the post. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have pm2 running on a server with mongoose/MongoDB and no problems. It looks like it might be with how you are handling your creation of a mongoose model.

Try doing:

```
StockMoment.create({
                symbol: body[i].symbol,
                price: body[i].price,
                size: body[i].size,
                time: body[i].time,
            });
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html

You shouldn't have to use the save when you initially create a document.

Also, I don't know how familiar you are with mongo, but make sure you select the database with `use stock-test` when in the console. On the off change that you are using python to read your database, you might also run into an issue with the "-" due to how python handles that character in its dictionaries.

Comment: I am using `use dbName`, thanks for the heads up. I tried changing it to `.create` but it doesn't seem to actually create anything. It just stops after making all the requests...

Comment: Actually, looks like that works. I had to restart the service after editing the file. Didn't know that. It is successfully making the request and saving the file. Just have to see if it will work during stock market hours. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you using a promise library with Mongoose? I've honestly never setup without one, and you will need an `await` with all methods that access the database.

Comment: Well good! I forget about that. Nodemon has me spoiled (in development)